# Transform a monodimensional PHP array into a multidimensional one

Tags: php, arrays

How would you transform a monodimensional array into a multidimensional array in PHP? Suppose you have something like this

```
$array['breakfast'] = 'milk';
$array['meal.firstdish'] = 'pasta';
$array['meal.seconddish.maincourse'] = 'veal';
$array['meal.seconddish.dressing'] = 'fries';
$array['meal.dessert'] = 'pie';
```

And you want a function to transform it into

```
$array['breakfast'] = 'milk';
$array['meal']['firstdish'] = 'pasta';
$array['meal']['seconddish']['maincourse'] = 'veal';
$array['meal']['seconddish']['dressing'] = 'fries';
$array['meal']['dessert'] = 'pie';
```

The same function should of course transform

```
$tire['ean'] = '3286347717116';
$tire['brand.maker'] = 'BRIDGESTONE';
$tire['brand.model.name'] = 'POTENZA';
$tire['brand.model.variant'] = 'RE 040 RFT * SZ';
```

into

```
$tire['ean'] = '3286347717116';
$tire['brand']['maker'] = 'BRIDGESTONE';
$tire['brand']['model']['name'] = 'POTENZA';
$tire['brand']['model']['variant'] = 'RE 040 RFT * SZ';
```

I was thinking of using explode, then eval on the results, but eval always feels like cheating to me and I guess it would keep my code from running in HipHop.

The reason I want to do this is that I have to export lots of different tables from a database into XML files, and I already have a robust function that turns a multidimensional array into XML.

Comment: Please edit your code. You are missing lots of  's. Look at _['meal.firstdish]_ should be _['meal.firstdish']_ and also _['meal']['firstdish]_

Comment: Also,  what have you tried?

Comment: As I said, I thought I would do a`
while (list($keys,$value) = each($array)) {
 $individualKeys = explode ('.', $keys);
 eval ("\$newarray['".implode("']['", $individualKeys)."']='$value';");
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
function build(array &$trg, array $k,$key,$value) {
    $p = &$trg;
    while ( !empty($k) ) {
        $nk = array_shift($k);
        if ( !isset($p[$nk]) ) {
            $p[$nk] = [];
        }
        $p = &$p[$nk];
    }
    $p[$key] = $value;
    return $p;
}

$array['breakfast'] = 'milk';
$array['meal.firstdish'] = 'pasta';
$array['meal.seconddish.maincourse'] = 'veal';
$array['meal.seconddish.dressing'] = 'fries';
$array['meal.dessert'] = 'pie';

$out = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value ) {
       $path = explode('.',$key);
       $last = array_pop($path);
       build($out,$path,$last,$value);
}

print_r($out);
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this code? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with `explode`, but there's no need to use `eval`. Once you've got the pieces of the keys available, you can loop over them and incrementally assign a pointer into a new array:

```
<?php
$array['breakfast'] = 'milk';
$array['meal.firstdish'] = 'pasta';
$array['meal.seconddish.maincourse'] = 'veal';
$array['meal.seconddish.dressing'] = 'fries';
$array['meal.dessert'] = 'pie';

$result = [];
$target = null;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // Start by targeting the base of our resulting array
    $target =& $result;

    // Break the keys apart into pieces
    $keyParts = explode('.', $key);

    // Assign new target based on indexing into the result array one "piece" at a time
    while ($part = array_shift($keyParts)) {
        $target =& $target[$part];
    }

    // Finally, assign the value to our target
    $target = $value;
}
```

See https://eval.in/625627